# How to get a DropDownArrow in AutoComplete? (material-ui)

Tags: material-ui

I want to show a small arrow at the far left of the AutoComplete input box, (just like in the DropDownMenu).

Since both AutoComplete and Text fields look the same.

The closest I got to was setting `&#x25BC;` in the floatingLabelText.